# Jquery POST Json return

Tags: jquery, json, post

i have a jquery script, which posts my form. here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#submit").submit(function() {


var an      = $('#an').attr('value');
var betreff = $('#betreff').attr('value');
var text    = $('#text').attr('value');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "newmsg.php",
        data: "an="+ an +"& betreff="+ betreff +"&text="+ text,
        success: function(){

            $('#window').html(name);                

        }
    });
return false;
});
});
```

my newmsg.php file

```
<?php if($_POST['an']=="john") { echo json_encode(array("name"=>"hi john")); } ?>
```

my problem is, that my php file will not return the name, so my div #window does not post the message

hope you guys understand...

thank you very much

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
success: function(data){
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#window').html(json.name);                
}
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Remove the space in `"& betreff="`. Could be messing it up. Also check the console.

Comment: i dont want to print the input form. i want to print the returnmessage from the php file :\ ...printing the inputs does work

Comment: I meant for you to change data: `"an="+ an +"& betreff="+ betreff +"&text="+ text` to `data: "an="+ an +"&betreff="+ betreff +"&text="+ text`

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, it's working for me - http://jsfiddle.net/Tc65k/ - did you check the console?

Answer (score 2):

this is prob the part you have wrong

```
$('#an').attr('value');
```

if id=an is a input it should be done this way

```
$('#an').val();
```

if id=an is a container it should be done this way

```
$('#an').html();
```

you'll want to change the rest of these too

```
var betreff = $('#betreff').attr('value');
var text    = $('#text').attr('value');
```

Comment: your welcome, so why did you choose the other answer as your solution?